# AJAX Beginner: If then statement

Tags: javascript, ajax

In menu.html, I have my menu items(a href links), let's call them, menu_1, menu_2, ....

In map.js displays the contents of a map, it calls an API to display some layers and maps. I have a lot of maps to show but i only want to call the api once.

Using AJAX, I was wondering if it's possible to have an if/then or select/case in my js, so that if menu_1 is clicked, then implement map_1 etc. without having the page to reload. The only way I thought I could do this is using Post/get .. so when you click on menu_1 it takes you to page.php?page_id=1 . JS will read that and display the map.

I'm new to JS and AJAX so please feel free to butcher me

Comment: Definitely use a framework for AJAX work, especially if you're new to JS and AJAX. I just started using jQuery regularly about two months ago, and now I'm able to write very intricate AJAX methods. Having that platform to work from makes things so much easier. Refer to the answers below for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact if you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can just add `click` event handlers to each of these links:

jQuery("#my_menu_item").click( function(){
       // Do something when the menu item is clicked...
   } );

You might then use [jQuery.post](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2FjQuery.post%2F&ei=V1iiS-XzJoaglAe-n9DXCA&usg=AFQjCNHwpa0KUYZqVvVwXY5sIVnyWHgTTg&sig2=yn4dbnf_kBa611BdYLUayw) or [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to retrieve the URL and update your page.

Answer (score 1):

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ohaxa/4/edit

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu li > a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var my_id = $(this).attr('id'); // li a #

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax_call.php",
   data: "action=do_something&my_id=" + my_id,
   success: function(data){

     my_function(my_id); //run your outside function...

    //OR use "data" from the php echo and append it to DOM 
    // $(#ajax_call_back).append(data); 

   },
  complete: function(data){
     //on complete do something..
   },
  error: function(data){
     //this here for demo pseudo ajax handle error instead!
     my_function(my_id);

   },
 }); 

});
});

function my_function(id) {
  alert(id);
  var map = '';

  switch(id)
{
case 1:
map = id;  //map_1
  break;
case 2:
map = id;  //map_2
  break;
case 3:
map = id;  //map_3
  break;
default:
map = id;  //map_0
}

 $('#application').text('map_' + map);  

};
```

​

```
     <ul id="menu">
           <li><a href="#" id="1">menu_1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" id="2">menu_2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" id="3">menu_3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" id="4">menu_4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" id="5">menu_5</a></li>
        </ul>

     <div id="application"></div>
  <div id="ajax_call_back"></div>
```